# What resolution works best?

Tags: 11.04, hardware, laptop, resolution, screen

I want to buy a laptop and install Ubuntu 11 on it. Is there a particular screen resolution or dimension that is ideal?

For example, if I'm choosing between 1600 x 900 or 1680 x 1050, these have different ratios of height to width, and the second is (as far as I know) a less common resolution.

Will any of these things matter, or are all resolutions that a major retailer sells be supported seamlessly?

Part of the reason for my question is that I had a little trouble with Ubuntu 9 on a monitor with a 4:3 ratio.

Comment: it depends on what you want, how big you want it as for ubuntu works fine in 800x600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends more on the graphics card and the drivers.

You are able to use 11.04 without problems as long as the resolution is higher than 1024x768.(I prefer 1280x800 or higher)